# GNU Make and using ; to execute multiple shell commands in the same command shell

Tags: windows, shell, makefile

I have a very basic problem using GNU Make 3.81 on Windows, I must be doing something very silly and I'm sure someone here will point it out in milliseconds.  My problem is with using ";" to run multiple commands in the same shell.

As I understand it, make runs each line in its own command shell and so if you want to run two commands, one after the other, you must put them on the same line separated by a semicolon.  In it's simplest form:

```
all:
    echo hello; echo hello
```

...should produce the output:

```
hello
hello
```

But for me it produces the output:

```
hello; echo hello
```

In other words, the semicolon is being passed straight through to the shell, which doesn't make too much sense for cmd.exe.

I'm now ready to be embarrassed by everyone pointing out where I've gone wrong...

FYI, the reason I need this is that I'm using a $(foreach) loop which must execute two shell commands for each iteration.

Comment: You might be interested in [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#One-Shell)

Comment: I suspect that wouldn't fix my problem as I still need to construct the multi-command thing in the $(foreach) loop and I don't believe that allows my to pass actual newlines to the shell.  But I do now understand what the devil .ONESHELL is :-).

Comment: use `$(shell echo hello; echo hello)`

Answer (score 5):

You are be under the impression that `;` is a GNU-make operator for executing multiple
commands in the same shell within a recipe. Not so. It is *linux* shell operator
for punctuating a sequence of commands on the same line. It is not an operator for
the Windows shell, `cmd`, so when the recipe:

```
 echo hello; echo hello
```

is executed by `make` on Linux, it has the output you expect, but when executed by `make`
on Windows it just means *echo this*:

```
hello; echo hello
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, yes, that would explain it.  The GNU Make documentation doesn't make it clear that the shell _must_ be able to understand semicolons, it says that "the shell will execute the statements in sequence"; plainly this is not so on Windows.  It's been pointed out to me that most people running make on Windows tend to get a shell that comes with it in the bargain.  I just wanted to keep things simple and use only make.  The workaround, for my case, is to used define/endef to define the sequence of commands and then call that from my foreach() loop.

Comment: @Rob You're referring to [5.3 Recipe Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) The shell will execute the statements in sequence, according - of course - to the operative
shell's definition of "statement". That is as true on Windows as on Linux. Semi-colons are not mentioned. You need to write `cmd` statements for execution by `cmd` and write `bash` statements
for execution by `bash` - in `make` recipes as in any other context.

Comment: Sorry, I quoted the wrong text, I was looking at [Writing The Commands In Rules](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_5.html), where it says under _Command Execution_: "If you want to use cd to affect the next command, put the two on a single line with a **semicolon** between them. Then make will consider them a single command and pass them, together, to a shell which will execute them in sequence".

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer is that your shell is the thing that has to understand that `;` separates multiple commands on the same line, it's nothing to do with make. This is not the case for Windows `cmd.exe` but is presumably the case for the shells that normally arrive with environments that use make (Linux, msys etc.).  In my case, a good workaround was this:

```
define useDef
  echo hello
  echo hello
endef

all:
    $(call useDef)
```

With this form of "single-lined" definition I can invoke a multiline shell command inside $(foreach).  Make still does each "hello" in its own shell but in my case that's OK because I'm appending outputs to a file. If you need two commands to be run in the same shell for some reason then, on Windows, you would need to write a separate batch file (which I suppose you could create from inside the makefile).

Comment: Or, as @user657267 said, if you need shell commands to be run in sequence in a single shell, `.ONESHELL` might be your answer, no need for a messy batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is relatively old, but I've stumbled across the same problem recently. The solution (for me) was quite simple. I replaced `;` with `&`.

Basically

```
all:
    echo hello & echo hello
```

will produce

```
hello
hello
```

in cmd.exe.

And it works with $(foreach) loops as well.

UPD: You also can use `&&` instead of `&` if you don't want your commands to fail silently.